# Want to change the range of for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm not sure how for loops work in Python 3:

```
l=6
for z in range(l):
    print(z)
```

Can I change the value of `l` by setting `l=10` from within the loop?
Will the value of `l` will be changed to 10 or will remain 6?

If not, how can I manipulate the range from within the loop?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot manipulate the range from within the loop.

`range(l)` will be evaluated **once** to a list containing numbers from `0` to `l-1`, when the code execution reaches the line with the `for` statement:

```
range(l) => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then the for loop will assign the values in the list to `z` in order.

If you need more fine grained control you'd have to use a while loop and keep a counter manually:

```
l = 6
z = 0
while z < l:
    print(z)
    z = z + 1
    l = 10
```

This would allow you to check on every iteration for a stopping criterion.

Comment: @AnkushVerma please accept the answer if it solves your problem